# iOS 7 App Operations Running In Background; Saving a Video Recording In Background

Tags: ios7, background, background-process

I am currently trying to find the most efficient way to continue a method in the background of my app. 
I am probably adding location/gps to my app soon, so I was considering using that flag to keep the app Active in the background. However, I do not want to add that flag yet because I want to post an App Update before I add the location functionality.

I know the exceptions;

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Besides asking for a more generic idea then these ^, can someone explain the "external accessory" flag please? I am recording video from an outside device. However, I do not know what constitutes an "external accessory".

I also see that iOS7 has introduced new Multi-tasking functionality but I haven't seen any examples that I understand can someone also explain that? Maybe that is a viable solution?

Thanks in advance!